# JavaFX on Juno with JDK1.6

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, eclipse-juno

is it possible to install JavaFX on Eclipse Juno?
The problem is that I have JDK1.6

When I try to install e(fx)clipse by following the guide found here:
http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html
however I receive the following error at step 6:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: e(fx)clipse - IDE 2.0.0.201503100708 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201503100708)
>     Missing requirement: org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.cssext.ui 2.0.0.201503100708 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.cssext.ui 2.0.0.201503100708) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.databinding.property 1.4.200' but it could not be found
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: e(fx)clipse - IDE - CSS 2.0.0.201503100708 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201503100708)
>       To: org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.cssext.ui [2.0.0.201503100708]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: e(fx)clipse - IDE 2.0.0.201503100708 (org.eclipse.fx.ide.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201503100708)
>       To: org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.feature.feature.group [2.0.0.201503100708]

Due to this installation occuring on a system at work, I do not have many options in terms of permissions, I am not able to download a more up to date JDK, I am not able to update to Java8 (I am on Java6).

Does anyone have any ideas of where I can go next?

Comment: Java 6 has been [EOL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) since 2/2013. Java 7 is EOL next month (4/2015). Why can't you upgrade?

Comment: Instead of a system install, you could do one for you privately. Otherwise: consider firing the sys admin if he/she sticks with obsolete JDK's.

Comment: does this mean I am going have to use Swing instead?